# How to make a tableview snap to cells centers ? (with gif animation illustration)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gallery

The thing I want to achieve is a gallery, it can contain up to 300 images, using a `UIScrollView` will result in non optimized ram/cpu usage since it doesn't do pooling (correct me if I'm wrong), and it has a limitation on width, I can't make it 300 times the width of the screen (again correct me if I'm wrong).

so the right choice would be to use a `UITableView`

1 - how to make it scroll horizontally like in this gif ?

2 - how to make it snap to cells centers ?

[image: gif]

**EDIT**

I'm using this, it gives the result I want but it has a problem, it has no tolerance for how much I should swipe to move to the next cell, I still need help..

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
{
    // Find collectionview cell nearest to the center of collectionView
    // Arbitrarily start with the last cell (as a default)
    var closestCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.visibleCells()[0];
    for cell in collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell]
    {
        let closestCellDelta = abs(closestCell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0)
        let cellDelta = abs(cell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0)
        if (cellDelta < closestCellDelta)
        {
            closestCell = cell
        }
    }
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(closestCell)
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    // Find collectionview cell nearest to the center of collectionView
    // Arbitrarily start with the last cell (as a default)
    var closestCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.visibleCells()[0];
    for cell in collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell]
    {
        let closestCellDelta = abs(closestCell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0)
        let cellDelta = abs(cell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0)
        if (cellDelta < closestCellDelta)
        {
            closestCell = cell
        }
    }
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(closestCell)
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

EDIT :-

I managed to do it without above code.

Comment: i think you want a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/)

Comment: To make horizontal scroll UITableView, you have to rotate your UITableView and each Cell. If you want to change only 1 page by swipe, you can use UIPageViewController.

Comment: checkout `UICompositionalLayout` with `NSCollectionLayoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior` = `.groupPagingCentered`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) with one cell or [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/) to achieve this kind of effect. There is no way to use tableview horizontally. Somehow you can say `UICollectionView` as a horizontal representation of `UITableView`. `UIPageViewcontroller` is also good solution. You should read about both in detail and then decide what's more suitable for you!

and yes that's not good to use single scroll view with that much different size. It can create memory or performance issue!!

**Update :**

Have you tried to enable paging in your collection view's scroll view ?

look at screenshot below

[image]

Check the checkbox paging enable!

then after If you not feel smooth effect then you should try to `uncheck adjust scroll view insets` under `viewcontroller` under `attribute inspector` which you got by selecting your `view controller`

check the screenshot for that

[image]

---

**EDIT** by person who asked the question : -

adding this worked for me, as `UICollectionView` don't have 
`adjust scroll view insets` option.

```
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

---

Comment: thanks, I know how to use a UICollectionView, I will read about UIPageViewcontroller, and see what happens.

Comment: how to uncheck [adjust scroll view insets] programmatically, i can apply it on self.view but not on the collection view?

Comment: select your view controller from storyboard () (viewcontroller - yellow square icon exact right from file responder). with selected viewcontroller select `attribute inspector` from the `utilities`. under `attribute inspector` you will found that option

Comment: i built the collectionview programatically, anyway, it's solved now, instead of that option i used these layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

now all works, thanks.

Comment: please add this info to your answer so i accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UICollectionView and configure collection view cell

set collectionViewLayout size... This size based on above view

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(250, 150);
}